# Struts Map References in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts, el

My question is more complex than below, but I've tried to simplify things out.

I have something like the following for my form:

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm {
    private Map<Long, String> myValues;

    public MyForm() {
        setMyValues(new HashMap<Long, String>());
    }

    public Map<Long, String> getMyValues() {
        return myValues;
    }

    public void setMyValues(Map<Long, String> myValues) {
        this.myValues = myValues;
    }

    public Object getMyValue(String key) {
        return getMyValues().get(key);
    }

    public void setMyValue(String key, Object value) {
        getMyValues().put(Long.valueOf(key), value.toString());
    }
}
```

If I try this in my JSP page for the form, all of the lines are value except the last one:

```
<c:forEach items="${MyForm.myValues}" var="mapEntry">
    <c:out value="${mapEntry.value}" />
    <c:out value="${mapEntry.key}" />
    <c:out value="${MyForm.myValue(mapEntry.key)}" />
</c:forEach>
```

The last line causes the page to break with "The function myValue must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified". Does anyone know the correct way to access the map value for a specific key? As I said, it's more complex than the above. I need something similar to that last line to work.

### UPDATE

Note that the following does work, where # is any integer:

```
<textarea name="myValue(#)"><textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediate value:

```
<c:out value="${MyForm.myValues[1]}" />
```

Key from form value:

```
<c:out value="${MyForm.myValues[MyForm.anId]}" />
```

Key from request attribute:

```
<c:out value="${MyForm.myValues[wat]}"/>
```

Why use `<c:out>`? We have JSP EL.

```
${MyForm.myValues[wat]}
```

Comment: As to using `<c:out>`, it's useful to escape user-controlled input against XSS attacks.

Comment: @BalusC True, although it should be scrubbed on the server side.

Comment: Yes, that is why I use `<c:out>`. Just another line of defense.

Comment: Using `<c:out value="${MyForm.myValues[mapEntry.key]}" />` worked. Thanks for the help. +1

Comment: It already runs on the server side. I think that you actually mean, during processing of the input instead of during processing of the output? I tend to disagree on this as that's harder to control properly on all layers.

Comment: @BalusC Non-view layer. I don't, because escaping via c:out escapes indiscriminately. That may meet a requirement, it just almost never meets mine.